# jqGrid, rowedit, php posts names instead of values to the db

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I need to dynamically edit and change the server data.

http://pssnet.com/~devone/ajqtable/editgrid2.html

Right now, when the fields get edited php posts names instead of
values to the db. My assumption is that on submit, the editurl will be called upon with
the changed data. I read in the docs that I may have to add an onSubmit function (as
shown below).

```
<?php
  include("dbc.php");
  $var1 = $_POST['service_id'];
  $var2 = $_POST['name'];

  // $var1 = "abc";
  // $var2 = "xyz";

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO
 testwrite (service_id, name) 
 VALUES('$var1', '$var2') ")
 or die(mysql_error());
?>

onclickSubmit : function(eparams) 
{
 var retarr = {};
 // we can use all the grid methods here
 //to obtain some data
 var sr = jQuery("#grid_id").getGridParam('selrow');
 rowdata = jQuery("#grid_id").getRowData(sr);
 if(rowdata.somevalue=='aa') {
    retarr = {myname:"myvalue"};
}
return retarr;
```

Thank you for you help.

Regards,
Nat

Answer (score 1):

I like the jquery plugin editInPlace
http://davehauenstein.com/code/jquery-edit-in-place/example/
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/

Answer (score 0):

I got it.....

I had it as editdata{name: 'name', etc}

editdata is a function to send additional data.....

So...thanks....if any of you look at it...

Regards,
Nat